# Elliptical structured confusing English

Tags: american-english

1.She believed to have been killed in somewhere in frontline

-->>: For me it should be written in like "She is believed 'who' have been killed in somewhere in frontline"
2. After the peace treaty everyone has paid but only he paying nothing

-->: For me article it should be written in like "After the peace treaty everyone has paid but he 'has paid' nothing"

The question is inside no1 paragraph 'To' used replacing 'Who' and no2 'paying' used replacing 'has paid'?

Comment: Could you answer?

Comment: @BillJ Flag it for migration, then.

Comment: Both sentences are ungrammatical - where did you find them?

Comment: I found them in newspaper

Comment: The sentences in the question are either ungrammatical or logically nonsensical. (If everyone has paid, then he must have also, because he is someone …)